# Weird behaviour of part of jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, lets begin.

this code works fine in console, doing what is required from it.

```
$('#tasks-table input').parent().html($('#tasks-table input').siblings('textarea').val())
```

but in such a call it doesn't even execute. console is silent. all other function code is executed properly

```
updateTask.call(this, 131)
```

any ideas?

**update**

this

```
$('#tasks-table input').parent().html($('#tasks-table input').siblings('textarea').val())
```

is part of this

```
updateTask.call(this, 131)
```

and gets ignored in updateTask
this instruction works from console just fine, but does not when it's a part of updateTask

html is a 4-row php-generated table with a row typical to this

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $task->id ?></td>
  <td onclick='projects.editTask.call(this, <?php echo $task->id ?>)'><?php echo $task->text ?> </td>
  <td><?php echo $task->status ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $task->controls ?></td>
</tr>
```

editTask is a simple replace function(contents of td turned into textarea)

```
if(block || !($(this).attr('incomplete'))) return; //only one is allowed
block = true;
if(!$(this).children('textarea').length) {
   $(this).html('<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 110px;">'+$(this).html()+'</textarea><br/><input type="button" value="Сохранить" onclick="projects.updateTask.call(this, '+parseInt(id)+')" />');
}
```

the goal of updateTask is to replace anything within td back to contents of textarea and send an update request back to server using $.post
contents of updateTask

```
var text = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();
//does not work only here, but works anywhere else
$('#tasks-table input').parent().text($('#tasks-table input').siblings('textarea').val())
$.post('/projects/ajax/', {
   ajax: true,
   command: 'update',
   id: id,
   text: text }
  , function() { 
     block = false; 
  });
```

When I do it more complicated way, it works. more simple way like this one:

```
$(this).parent().html(text)
```

didn't work too

Comment: Did you check to see if your selectors are working?

Comment: Based on what you've posted I don't see how the code chunks you posted are even related.

Comment: update task is a function, part of Projects object, called in non-object context

Comment: Instead of storing the original cell contents in a `textarea`, why not store it in [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) on the element? The dynamic addition/querying of the `textarea` seems to be causing problems.

Comment: Because they are intended to be edited in that textarea =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
Revisiting your question, it looks like the point I focused on may not be exactly the problem. I won't delete it because it is a valid issue with the code you posted. The issue with the textarea value not being queried or modified is most likely because you're adding the `textarea` after the DOM has loaded. You should be able to use a [jquery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event on your table or the delegate event at the end of this post. Both are valid for any current or future DOM elements.  These are a life saver when performing any DOM manipulation or ajax-based HTML updates. This would also explain why you're able to perform the operation in the console and not in the code.

**Original answer:**
I'm not sure if this will help fully, but I think what is preventing your code from executing is:

```
if(block || !($(this).attr('incomplete'))) return;
```

When your table cells don't have that attribute, you're actually executing:

```
if( block || !(undefined) ) return;
```

Which will always be true because `!(undefined)` is true. You most likely want to be forcing a boolean value:

```
if( block || !!(undefined) ) return;
```

This is fine if you are only expecting `undefined` and any text value. A better way to modify this condition is to explicitly check the value you're expected (and I'm assuming you expect to be "true"):

```
if(block || ($(this).attr('incomplete') === "true") ) return;
```

**Suggestion:**

One suggestion I would make is instead of inlining the onclick function, use HTML5 data-* attributes to store your data and perform the code in one place. This helps keep JavaScript in a single place and doesn't mix it throughout the HTML.

For example, you can generate a `data-id` attribute for each table cell and mark your table row editable with `data-edit-cell="true"`

```
<table>
<tr data-edit-cell="true">
  <td data-id="1">cell one</td>
  <td data-id="2">cell two</td>
  <td data-id="3">cell three</td>
  <td data-id="4">cell four</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Then, a second suggestion, instead of binding a click event to each cell , you can bind an event to the row using  [jquery.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which watches for bubbling events (*click*) of a child defined by a selector (*td*):

```
var block = false;
$('tr[data-edit-cell=true]').delegate('td', 'click', function() {
    if (block || $(this).attr('incomplete') === "true" ) return; //only one is allowed
    block = true;
    console.log('clicked: ' + $(this).attr('data-id'));
});​
```

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/Daur8/1/) so you can check this code out.

Comment: jquery update fixed my problem, but thanks for revealing me data attributes usefullness =)